# Prevent Propel from inserting empty strings

Tags: php, mysql, propel

How can I prevent Propel ORM from inserting empty strings when a column is not set?

```
CREATE TABLE user (  
  uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,  -- No default value
  ...  
) Engine InnoDB ... ;
```

Propel allows `$user = new User(); $user->save();`.
I have tried setting `SQL_MODE` but it doesn't help.

Comment: What column should get the NULL value?

Comment: No column :-) That's the point. If, in this case the `email` column, is not explicitly set, it shouldn't be part of the INSERT query executen by Propel?

Comment: Are you aware that that would lead to an SQL constraint violation?

Comment: Yes... it should, but it doesn't. I want it to fail, but it doesn't.

Comment: In that case, sorry, you're _doing it wrong_ :) See my answer for a suggestion of actually doing what you (probably) want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with a validator in the schema and then a check using the `validate()` method in your code. Here's an example:

```
<database ...>
  <table ...>
    <!-- the "required" attribute here only sets the DB property -->
    <column name="email" type="varchar" required="true" />
    ...
    <!-- Adds the unique index in the DB (but nothing in PHP code!) -->
    <unique>
      <unique-column name="email" />
    </Unique>
    ...
    <validator column="email">
      <!-- this validator rule makes the $obj->validate() method fail on null -->
      <rule name="required" message="The email is required!" />
      <!-- this validator rule makes the $obj->validate() method fail on empty string -->
      <rule name="minLength" value="1" message="The email cannot be blank!" />
      <!-- you could add a regular expression to only match email addresses here -->
      <rule name="match" value="/regular expression/" message="Please enter a valid email address!" />
      <!-- adds a validation that the field is unique before trying to update DB -->
      <rule name="unique" message="That email address is not unique!" />
    </validator>
  </table>
</database>
```

Then in your `preSave()` code you could do something like this:

```
class User extends BaseUser {
  ...
  public function preSave(PropelPDO $con = null) {
    // does the object pass all validations?
    if (!$this->validate()) {
      $errors = array();
      // something failed, go through each failure and capture message:
      foreach ($this->getValidationFailures() as $failure) {
        $errors[] = $failure->getMessage();
      }
      // throwing an Exception will stop the save() from occurring
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(implode("||", $errors));
    }

    return true; // if you get here, go ahead and save
  }
}
```

In your script you would call `save()` like so:

```
...
$user = new User();
try {
  // try to save (could fail)
  $user->save();

} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
  // we have errors, split the exception message to get each one separately
  $errorMessages = preg_split(/\|\|/, $e->getMessage());
  // handle the messages however you need to
}
```

Read more about [Validators in the Propel documentation](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/05-validators.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to stop the insert/update if the `email` column is not set. There actually is a proper way to do this, and that's by using [hooks](http://propelorm.org/documentation/07-behaviors.html).

See the following code for an example:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
  // rest of code ...

  public function preSave(PropelPDO $con = null)
  {
    if ( empty($this->getEmail) ) {
        return false; 
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

You can also use `preInsert()` or `preUpdate()` for more control about when to validate the data.

Comment: That's not actually a behavior, it's a hook into the `save` method. A behavior add code to the `Base*` classes and/or table (usually) and is defined by a `<behavior ...>` tag in the schema. That said, this would work.