# Column "" declared twice in table "status" in Propel 2

Tags: sql-server, propel

I'm trying to reverse generate a schema from a MSSQL database using Propel 2. I've set up my YAML configuration file as usual:

```
dbname:
    adapter: mssql
    classname: Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionWrapper
    dsn: "dblib:host=123.456.789.012;dbname=dbname"
    user: username
    password: password
    attributes:
```

When I run the command `propel reverse 'dbname'` I receive the error:

```
[Propel\Generator\Exception\EngineException]
Column "" declared twice in table "Status"
```

Which is obviously thrown here:
https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/blob/master/src/Propel/Generator/Model/Table.php#L499
@r499

Why does Propel attempt to add 'empty' columns? My SQL server management studio does not display empty columns at all when I look at the design of the DB table `Status`, it only displays the two columns it contains (`uid` and `name`).

Edit:
So I went digging into the code of Propel, and it seems to go wrong here:
https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/blob/62859fd0ed3520b7d7afbbdeac113edaf160982b/src/Propel/Generator/Reverse/MssqlSchemaParser.php#L124

```
 protected function addColumns(Table $table)
    {
        $dataFetcher = $this->dbh->query("sp_columns '" . $table->getName() . "'");
        foreach ($dataFetcher as $row) {
            $name = $this->cleanDelimitedIdentifiers($row['COLUMN_NAME']);
```

`$table->getName()` correctly returns the right table name. When I print dataFetcher it's a PDO object. However:
`$row` gives the following array:

```
Array(
    [0] => My DBname
    [1] => My DBprefix
    [2] => Status
    [3] => uid
    [4] => 4
    [5] => int identity
    etc. no string indices hence COLUMN_NAME is empty.
```

Comment: For the sake of purely backend guys like me,could you share the original table structure please? Which table is throwing error, and the columns?

Comment: I don't have access right now,but on top of my head the table contains 2 columns; `uid` of type int and `name` of type varchar. I suspect it might be due to the name of the table (`Status`) which might lead to an unexpected result when querying the DB for the tables and their columns. I'll try this out tomorrow and report back here.

Comment: Renaming `Status` to any other name did not work, so I dropped the table and recreated it (this 'worked', but most likely since its now at the tail of the list of tables to work through), however now the same problem occurs for another table. Unfortunately I don't see any empty column names in my SQL server management studio.

Comment: A quick google search yields this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16212374/2993606 Can you see if this is of any help?

Comment: Took a look at it, that's actually different. It concerns inserting something using Propel (and it should ignore empty columns to be inserted). I narrowed the problem down to this line of code: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/blob/62859fd0ed3520b7d7afbbdeac113edaf160982b/src/Propel/Generator/Reverse/MssqlSchemaParser.php#L124 This actually gives an array with numeric indices and hence the index `COLUMN_NAME` among others is empty. I'll edit my question for more details.

Comment: So I guess you found the reason then?

Comment: I think I did. It appears their dataFetcher always use `FETCH_NUM` hence this piece of code simply can't work, but I might be wrong. Anyways, I opened an issue on their git: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/863

Comment: Try the following code and see the results `SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Status'`. This should give you some hint as to why this is happening.

Comment: Propel 2 is still in alpha as far as I know, so maybe (depending how far into development you are with it) you could switch to 1.7 or master of the 1.x branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*:

This is a bug in the Propel MSSQL schema parser: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/863.